# Get pagination automatically instagram with Python

Tags: python, instagram

I'm trying to automate my script(in Python) to automatically get the end_cursor in succession. For example:

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/plebiscito/?__a=1
```

after:

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/plebiscito/?__a=1&max_id=J0HWFB4fAAAAF0HWE8Y4AAAAFiYA
```

after:

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/plebiscito/?__a=1&max_id=J0HWFB4fAAAAF0HWE2jPAAAAFkwA
```

....
....
....

And do so, until the end of the last end_cursor.
I would appreciate it if you would help me, since I could not. Thank you very much again.

PD: I'm not doing it with the API, because of the problem that the Sandbox does not allow applications in development.

Update: End_cursor is in everything that loads when entering the link

Comment: I think some more details about the data returned by the URLs you're mentioning would be helpful in getting this question answered. Where are you getting `end_cursor` from? I don't see it referenced at all. Please update the question.

Comment: If you find yourself, look:
"{"tag": {"media": {"count": 18924, "page_info": {"has_previous_page": false, "start_cursor": "1404546685791413124", "end_cursor":XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Comment: Agreed that it's easy to get, but it's better to have the question a bit more self-contained.

Comment: (I wasn't sure if an API key or authentication of some kind would be needed.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, `https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/plebiscito/?__a=1` returns a bunch of JSON that starts off like

```
{"tag": {"media": {"count": 18926, "page_info": {"has_previous_page": false, "start_cursor": "1404693250132394506", "end_cursor": "J0HWFCHOgAAAF0HWE8dgwAAAFiYA", "has_next_page": true}, "nodes": [{"code": "BN-eRGQh8IK", "dimensions": {"width": 750, "height": 538}, "comments_disabled": false, "owner": {"id": "311016089"}, "comments": {"count": 1}, "caption": "#plebiscito", "likes": {"count": 11}, "date": 1481672506, "thumbnail_src": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/c147.0.750.750/15338447_1774364399481982_8165079596765544448_n.jpg?...
```

After parsing the JSON, you can grab `end_cursor`:

```
end_cursor = data['tag']['media']['page_info']['end_cursor']
```

and then retrieve the next URL.

I couldn't get to the end of the list in a few seconds of doing this manually, so I don't know what happens for the last `end_cursor`. But I did notice the `has_next_page` key. Perhaps something like this, then:

```
data = json.loads(however_youre_getting_the_data('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/plebiscito/?__a=1'))
end_cursors = []
while data['tag']['media']['page_info']['has_next_page']:
    end_cursors.append(data['tag']['media']['page_info']['end_cursor'])
    data = json.loads(however_youre_getting_the_data('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/plebiscito/?__a=1&max_id={}'.format(end_cursors[-1])))
```

Comment: If it ends up working, be sure to mark it "correct" once Stack Overflow lets you. :)

Comment: This works, what button is that to score? thank you very much Scott :)!

Comment: Would there be any way to do it but without any while or loop? @Scott Colby

Comment: You could do it with recursion, but that has issues with the recursion limit. What is the argument against a loop? What you're doing is a fundamentally looping behavior...performing an action until a condition matches a value.

Comment: What happens is that I need to collect the data regarding the "code:", if done with a while, you can not take the url as an individual @Scott Colby

Comment: Create a list before the while loop, like I did with `end_cursors = []` and append to it inside the loop. Another option is to create a generator function and report out the data you're interested with `yield` and consume that as an iterable.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try, total, with your solution I will adapt. @Scott Colby

Comment: I have the code, I have almost everything, I just need to do the pagination, can you help me? Thanks (so I update my question with the code) @Scott Colby
Of course, I also have what you helped me with but I do not know how to integrate it